# How to truncate a text using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to truncate my URL using regex for example if I have

```
http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg
```

I need to read the url till `http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp` remaining i need to ignore.

If i use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\".*");
```

I am getting complete url kindly help me.

Comment: *How* do you want to "truncate" your input? Is `.jsp` *always* the end of the part you are interested in?

Comment: Tichodroma/ hmjd thanks for Your replay, actually i have a paragraph where i will be having a number of url i need to alter the urls for that i am using href in the pattern to identify the url, but when i say Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\".*"); it is reading entire paragraph, how can i avoid this using regex patterns. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "href=\"http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg\"";    
System.out.println(test);    

Matcher mtch = Pattern.compile("href=\"(http://.*\\.jsp).*\"").matcher(test);    
System.out.println(mtch.group(1));
```

would print out:

```
href="http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg"
http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

While Regex could certainly do what you ask, it would be more efficient to do like so:

```
String url = "http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg";
String desired = url.subString( 0, url.lastIndexOf( '/' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore everything after `.jsp` then you need:

```
String foo = "http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg";
String bar = foo.replaceAll("\\.jsp.*", ".jsp");
```

That is, take `.jsp` (escape the period with `\` otherwise it means *"any character"*) and everything after `.jsp` (`.*`) and replace it with just `.jsp`.

Or, if you want to only capture stuff that's prefixed by `href=` then you could use:

```
String foo = "href=\"http://abcdef.defgh/klmno.jsp/abdcefg\"";
String bar = foo.replaceAll("(href=.*\\.jsp)[^\"]*\"", "$1");
```

That is, capture everything that starts with `href=`, up to `.jsp` (greedy match will ensure up to the final `.jsp`), and use it as a back reference (`$1`). Exclude everything after that last `.jsp` up to the final quote `[^\"]*\"`.